# Why is the c# casting syntax defined as (AnyType) obj rather than AnyType(obj)?

Tags: c#

Why is the c# casting syntax defined as (AnyType) obj rather than AnyType(obj) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep syntax as C-like as practical, which has it this way to avoid confusing a cast with a function call.

Comment: Avoid confusing a cast with a constructor call. Understood!

Comment: C++ though does allow `AnyType(obj)` so it would not have been foreign to the syntax C# decided to use (esp. since it's closer to clean C++ than to clean C). I would say it was the matter of avoiding function-call ambiguity more than being C-like in a way C++ wasn't, that was the main reason.